# When I insert a file in an input file it shows preview, but how to delete a selected file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got this javascript to show image preview when user select the file, it is working.
Case:
- If user select wrong image and delete it then preview do not refresh to 'empty'.
I have no idea how can I do this, already lookd around google and stackoverflow and nothing. Can someone give me a light please?

```
<img id="image1" width="300px" height="300px"/>
<img id="image2" width="300px" height="300px"/>
<img id="image3" width="300px" height="300px"/>
<img id="image4" width="300px" height="300px"/>

<script>
    document.getElementById("productimage1").onchange = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("image1").src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        };
    document.getElementById("productimage2").onchange = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("image2").src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        };
    document.getElementById("productimage3").onchange = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("image3").src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        };
    document.getElementById("productimage4").onchange = function () {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                document.getElementById("image4").src = e.target.result;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        };
</script>
```

Comment: _"If user select wrong image and delete it then preview do not refresh to 'empty'"_ What do you mean by "delete it" and "refresh to 'empty'"? You can  set specific `<img>` element `.src` property to empty string `""`

Comment: Post `FileReader()` function.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i havent, this is bootstrap or jquery i guess

Comment: Okay... Then post how user deletes the file.

Comment: Does something like this would do? [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/VpgKaj?editors=1010)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette this works but if user select first image then "open windows files" and CANCEL (not selecting) then the image still will be there

Comment: If user cancels the "open file" window... Just nothing appens... Right. This is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get what you want correctly...

You want the image preview to be cleared when user tries to select a new image using the "open file" window. No delete button.

Here is what you should do then:

```
// A delete function
$("[id^='product']").on("click",function(){

  // This clears the input value.
  $(this).val("");

  // This resets the preview.
  var imageID = $(this).attr("id").substr(7);
  $("#"+imageID).attr("src","https://placehold.it/300x300");
});
```

See in [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/PpVbKL?editors=1010)

---

**---EDIT**

Here is the full code *optimized*.

```
// A delete function
$("[id^='product']").on("click",function(){

  // This clears the input value.
  $(this).val("");

  // This resets the preview.
  var imageID = $(this).attr("id").substr(7);
  $("#"+imageID).attr("src","https://placehold.it/300x300");
});


// The preview function
$("[id^='product']").on("change",function(){
  var imageID = $(this).attr("id").substr(7);

  // Displays a preview im the right div
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $("#"+imageID).attr("src",e.target.result);
  };
  reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

See in [**CodePen** - version #2](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/LWqyLe)

Comment: This really works, your code is optimized. Is my code optimizable?

Comment: I started from you code... Do you have issue pasting it (Or I don't get the question...)?

Comment: I mean your code is optimized. The code I post i guess isn't because I'm still learning. Could you please optimize mine too?

Comment: My code is to be added to yours. As is, it should work. I did not change what you posted.

Comment: I just through both could be merged into one. Thank you!