# save and display image captured from input type=file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input-type-file

I have a webpage with *capture image from the Available camera* feature. For the web version it simply places the video capture onto a canvas. However for a phone, I am using `<input class="btn btn-info" type="file" accept="image/*" id="cameraCapture" capture="camera">` to capture a picture. It asks the user to either capture the image using the phone's camera or upload from its filesystem/gallery etc. Once the image is clicked it simply places the image's name next to the button. 
Is there a way to access this image and display it in the same page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preview an image before it is uploaded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Comment: This answer could also help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/43161974/2159528

Comment: can you help me with this question please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69351438/how-to-put-captured-image-from-webcam-into-input-file

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with JS using `FileReader` object.

Take a look at this answer: [preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4459419/5384339)

I hope it helps

Comment: Please don't use the Answer field for links to other questions' answers. Once you have enough reputation, you can add comments, and after that you can flag questions as duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=file]'); 

input.onchange = function () {
    var file = input.files[0];


    drawOnCanvas(file);   
};

function drawOnCanvas(file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var dataURL = e.target.result,
                c = document.querySelector('canvas'), 
                ctx = c.getContext('2d'),
                img = new Image();

        img.onload = function() {
            c.width = img.width;
            c.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        };

        img.src = dataURL;
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

Comment: No idea to answer a 1y old question, beside `URL.createObjectURL` would be a better option then using the FileReader...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.